# pyspark dataframe data transformation with unique column values

Tags: sql, python-3.x, dataframe, select, pyspark

I am trying to learn pysaprk with sql functionalities or by dataframe group by solution itself.

Thanks.

df1:

```
Name     Place     Product
AA       Germany   pencil
AA       Germany   pen
AA       Germany   pen
BB       Holland   hat
BB       Holland   hat
BB       Holland   pen
CC       USA       laptop
CC       USA       laptop
CC       USA       charger
```

Expected output:

```
Name     Place     Product
AA       Germany   pencil, pen
BB       Holland   hat, pen
CC       USA       laptop, charger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use collect_set as

```
df.groupBy("Name","Place").agg(concat_ws(",",collect_set("Product")))
```